# Will the Raspberry Pi 2, running windows 10, be able to run the .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi2

As a .NET dev, the new raspberry pi 2 and "Windows 10 IoT Core Insider" mix sounds extremely interesting. Will I be able to run .NET applications on it? Which .NET profile would it be able to support - the Micro Framework or the full Framework?

I'm hoping to set up a lightweight OWIN or nancy server. There's no information online on .NET support yet: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/featured/raspberrypi2support

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj553518.aspx might help with this topic

Comment: Hi @BenjaminPaul - I had reworded it to get at what Choco really wanted to ask, which is a programming question, not a SuperUser question. He wants to know whether he can program using the .NET framework on the Pi. This is not a question for SuperUser, as it deals with programming. Programming questions belong on SO.

Comment: I think this is a valid question. However, since the RP 2 was just released, there won't be a whole lot of information on for several days to several weeks. I'm looking forward to seeing what type of .net development is supported on this device.

Comment: @GreenChili, if the question is reopened, you could post your link as part of an answer :)

Comment: No C# so no .net for Intel galileo or Raspberry Pi 2. As a .net dev also lack of .net would not add value to the popularity of this platform.

Comment: Can someone with channels into Microsoft ask their PM to take an official position on .NET/C# dev on the Windows IoT platform roadmap? We're trying at our end ...

Comment: The Raspberry Pi 2 will be able to run .NET universal apps: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheNewRaspberryPi2WillRunWindows10AndRunUniversalApps.aspx

Comment: Seems that th OS going to be called IoT and in support of the above link wll run universal apps. http://www.anandtech.com/show/9099/microsoft-hints-at-windows-10-iot-skus